# How to add chosen pixels to PixelGrabber, not whole image

Tags: java, awt

I have image and I want to read and write pixel to PixelGrabber object, but not whole image, but only specific part- every seven row of image (0 row, 7 row, 14 row, etc.).

Generally, we do something like that when we want to read/write pixels

```
im1=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(str1); 
pg1=new PixelGrabber(im1,0,0,-1,-1,false);
int width = pg1.getWidth();
int height = pg1.getHeight();
liczbaPikseli1=new int [width*height];
liczbaPikseli1=(int [])pg1.getPixels();
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Generally, if you have `im1=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(str1); pg1=new PixelGrabber(im1,0,0,-1,-1,false);int width = pg1.getWidth();int height = pg1.getHeight();liczbaPikseli1=new int [width*height];liczbaPikseli1=(int [])pg1.getPixels();` you can define size of area which you want to read/write. The problem is e.g. when you want to use every seven row of image and then writte it to table

Comment: it is better to update the question with what you have tried. rather than commenting it. if you update the question with that code we would easy to understand what happen next?